# Xcode 7.3 UIBarButtonItem enable() function doesn't work in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've got an UIBarButtonItem in my storyboard. Furthermore I've got an array, dependent on the array if empty the button should be disabled.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if filterOptionsArray.isEmpty{
            self.filterBarButtonItem.enabled = false
    }else{
            self.filterBarButtonItem.enabled = true
    }
}
```

This works fine for iOS 9 devices, but not for iOS 10. As you can see I use XCode 7.3 so I use Swift-Version 2.2. As I saw in the official developer documentation the function changed to `.isEnabled()` for Swift 2.3/3.0.

I'm not sure if that's the reason? Does anybody know a solution or workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess that the key point of this question is filterOptionsArray.

Comment: what is the type of "filterOptionsArray" ?

Comment: It's a String Array.. The bool value should be the same no matter which Swift-Version or iOS-Version I'm using.